# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "ir de picos pardos"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

Con frecuencia se usa la expresión *ir de picos pardos*:

> —¿Dónde está Juan?
>   —Pues se ha ido de parranda.
>   —¿Sabes a qué hora volverá?
>   —Qué va, cuando se va **de picos pardos** nunca se sabe a qué hora volverá.

Es decir, la expresión sirve para designar que se va uno a divertirse, con un pequeño matiz de perdición y nocturnidad: uno se va de picos pardos si se va de bares por la noche, pero no si se levanta temprano para ir a pasear por la montaña.

La Wikipedia tiene un artículo largo sobre la expresión en [Ir de picos pardos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ir_de_picos_pardos), donde apuntan diferentes elementos que he oído. Especialmente este:

> Carlos III impuso a las prostitutas la obligación de distinguirse mediante sayas de color pardo cortadas por los bajos en picos, aunque también se dice que "Ir de picos pardos" tiene que ver con las costumbres ligeras de los estudiantes del Siglo de Oro y sus acompañantes. Ellas, para identificar su condición de prostitutas, llevaban un cintillo pardo en el borde de la falda.

Carlos es del siglo XVIII y en el diccionario de 1780 ya existía la entrada:

> ANDARSE, Ó IRSE Á PICOS PARDOS
>   f. con que se da á entender, que alguno pudiendo aplicarse á cosas útiles y provechosas, se entrega á las inútiles, é insubstanciales, por no trabajar, y por andarse á la briba. Otiari, divagari.

Por lo que podría tener su lógica. Sin embargo, ¿es realmente este el origen de la expresión?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé su etimología verdadera, pero podemos excluir la de rey Carlos III.

Su primera entrada que he encontrado en un diccionario es de 1737:

> Andarse, o irse à *picos* pardos. Phrase con que se dá à entender que alguno, pudiendo aplicarse à cosas útiles y provechosas, se entrega à las inútiles è insubstanciales, por no trabajar, y por andarse à la briva.
>
> - [*Diccionario de Autoridades*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_CHEd9t6dY4C&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq="picos+pardos") (tomo V, 1737)

Esto es bastante antes que el reinado de rey Carlos III (10 de agosto de 1759 - 14 de diciembre de 1788). Además, la entrada cita dos usos de este frase del siglo anterior:

> Y los errantes, quando las pensáramos tener con nosotras fe fueran à buscar **picos pardos**, ò à la flor del berro.
>
> - [*Universidad de amor y escuelas de el interes*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=165dAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA22&dq="picos+pardos"), Salvador Jacinto Polo de Medina  (1640)

> Y como sus oficinas
>   son garitos de soldados,
>   dice que **se fue** con uno
>   su mujer **a picos pardos**
>
> - [*Ocios*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/aiso/pdf/03/aiso_3_1_033.pdf), Conde de Rebolledo (Vv. 53-56) (1660)

Hay aún más ejemplos del siglo XVI - XVIII:

> vos **andays os** por las calles
>   **a picos pardos** buscar
>   tomara la por la mano
>   a casa la fue a tornar
>
> - *Romance [Tercera parte de la Silva de varios romances]*, (1551)

> Aqui fue adonde di à el diablo la guerra, i adonde tuve por insensato , à el que tiene con que paliar en la paz, i viene à buscar **picos pardos**, i entre abismos de descommodidades anda solicitando su muerte.
>
> - [*La vida i hechos de Estevanillo Gonzalez*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=muZFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA248&dq="picos+pardos") (1646)

> La muica de aves dietrifimas, al compàs firmiimo de la naturaleza perpetua; y etas aves vnase lamen parleras, y otras cantòras mas no tienen harpados picos, por ecuar la fealdad, mas **fe andan à picos pardos**, y cantan que parece que encantan, y embelessan, o embelecan:
>
> - [*Origen y primeras poblaciones de España*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xf8Ho0EHYmwC&pg=PP94&dq="picos+pardos"), Juan Félix Girón (O.C.) (1686)

> Mesonera soy, señores, que es empleo más honrado mantenerse a quentas negras, que no **andarse à picos pardos**;
>
> - [*Obras posthumas lyricas sagradas de D. Joseph Perez de Montoro*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d5-dA3tcx64C&pg=PA420&dq="picos+pardos") (1736)